# R write files with variable by for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to use R to write many txt files with a variable.

Here is a vector

```
name <- c("Apple","Banana","Cat")
```

I would like to use a for loop in R to assign the value and use value as part of the file name.

```
for (i in length(name)){

"The name is i"    

assign(paste(name, i, sep = ""), i)

write.table("i.txt")

}
```

My expectation is to generate three txt files

```
Apple.txt
Banana.txt
Cat.txt
```

The context of each txt file is a sentence respectively.

```
The name is Apple
The name is Banana
The name is Cat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need `assign` to create some global objects if the aim is to write three `.txt` files.  Loop through the `name` directly create the values with `sprintf` or `paste`, then write it to `.txt` file

```
for (nm in name){

 val <- sprintf("The name is %s", nm)
 #or with `paste`
 #val <- paste0("The name is ", nm)

 #write.table(val, file = paste0(nm, ".txt"))
 #this can also be with `write` that will not generate the heading
 write(val, file = paste0(nm, ".txt"))
}
```

The reason why `write.table` returns two lines is because of the conversion to `data.frame`.  According to the `?write.table` description

> write.table prints its required argument x (after converting it to a
>   data frame if it is not one nor a matrix) to a file or connection.

Comment: Could you please explain why there are two lines in the file ? The first line is "x", the second line is  "1" "The name is Apple"

Comment: @user3631848  Just change `write.table` to `write` and you will have only line.  I thought you wanted to have a column header